# mysql: unknown option '--skip-innodb'

Tags: mysql, innodb

In trying to disable innodb by adding this to mysql config

```
 [mysql]
 skip-innodb
```

But I get the error shown in title.. I also tried to change [mysql] to [mysqld] with no luck.

SHOW ENGINES:
http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=iq7NqQhM

MySQL version: 5.5.34-0ubuntu0.13.10.1 (Ubuntu)

Comment: If the `--skip-innodb` option isn't recognised, it suggests that the InnoDB plugin isn't loaded. Can you start MySQL without the above option and run the query `SHOW ENGINES;`?

Comment: I added show engines command and mysql version in the question

Answer (score 0):

unless you are running an old version, you need to load the innodb engine, as the "mysql" database now uses it for its tables internal tables (ie. "mysql"), and so wont start without it

older versions you can exclude loading the innodb engine, per your example, so as to make it not load on restart

that said, innodb is better that myiasm for most use cases

EDIT:

you have to post more like meaningful my.cnf; show engines; show variables like "%...%", show status like "%...%"....

Comment: I added show engines command and mysql version in the question